# How do I send a sms message with Amazon sns by some time interval?

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-sns

```
sns = boto3.client('sns')
sns.publish(
    PhoneNumber = '+11234567890',
    Message = 'Simple text message'
)
```

Here's a example code to send a text to given number. But I want to have a time interval between two continuous send by same user. I know that button could be implemented in JavaScript. But it's not secure enough because user could change script in client side and remove this restriction. 
Is there any other solution with given API of SNS or I have to create extra cost in Database to store timestamp for given user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sns.publish` command is immediate. If you wish to delay sending, you would need to code a solution that waits before sending the request.

You could do this by triggering AWS Step Functions with a wait step, and then calling an AWS Lambda function to do the actual send. It's starting to make things rather complex.

Normally, if you have a web page calling an AWS function, it is preferable to put the logic on the back-end so that users cannot call AWS directly. Rather, the page triggers some code in AWS (eg Lambda via API Gateway, or a request to a REST application) and it performs the authentication and logic.